# Excel combine Vlookups

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two files one is a Project Register that holds key information on a project and the other is a Risk log.

There is a 1:m relationship between entries in the Register and the Risk log. What I need to do is combine all of a project risks into one cell inside the project register file.

The matching field in both files is the Project ID field

Is there a way I can do this using a vlookup variant or multiple nested vlookups?

Comment: I think so, but it's probably not pretty. `VLOOKUP` provides only one value, bit if you know how the highest possible `m` for a risk, you could use `m` nested `VLOOKUP`s.

Comment: How important is it that this gets done with `VLOOKUP`? A VBA user-defined function could do all of this, if you're willing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the user-defined function approach I mentioned (adapted from a different VLOOKUP-variant I already had made):

```
' Acts like VLOOKUP in a 1-to-many scenario by concatenating all values in matching rows
' instead of just returning the first match
Public Function VLOOKUP_MANY(lookup_value As String, lookup_range As Range, column_number As Integer, Optional delimiter As Variant) As Variant
    Dim vArr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim found As Boolean: found = False

    ' Set default delimiter
    If IsMissing(delimiter) Then delimiter = ", "

    ' Get values
    vArr = lookup_range.Value2

    ' If column_number is outside of the specified range, return #REF
    If column_number < LBound(vArr, 2) Or column_number > UBound(vArr, 2) Then
        VLOOKUP_MANY = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Search for matches and build a concatenated list
    VLOOKUP_MANY = ""
    For i = 1 To UBound(vArr, 1)
        If UCase(vArr(i, 1)) = UCase(lookup_value) Then
            VLOOKUP_MANY = VLOOKUP_MANY & delimiter & vArr(i, column_number)
            found = True ' Mark at least 1 result
        End If
    Next

    If found Then
        VLOOKUP_MANY = Right(VLOOKUP_MANY, Len(VLOOKUP_MANY) - Len(delimiter)) ' Remove first delimiter
    Else
        VLOOKUP_MANY = CVErr(xlErrNA) ' If no matches found, return #N/A
    End If
End Function
```

This will search the first column in the specified range for the specified value (same as VLOOKUP), but returns the values in the specified column number concatenated. It will return #N/A when no matches are found, and #REF if an invalid value is specified for the column number (e.g. you choose column 5 but only had a 4-column table).

In case you don't know about user-defined functions - you can just copy this VBA code into the VBE for a module in your workbook. Hit Alt+F11, go to `Insert > Module` at the top of the screen, then paste this code into the blank file that opens up. When you go to save, you'll have to save your workbook as Macro-Enabled (.xlsm) to keep the code working - Excel will remind you about this in the save screen.

Be forewarned: it's going to be slower than VLOOKUP as a result of having to look through the entire lookup range instead of being able to stop at the first match it finds.

If you're open to using an array formula instead, there are ways to speed up this sort of functionality for very large datasets...

---

Different version that leverages some of the benefits of array formulas to store lookup values and speedup subsequent calls:

```
' Acts like VLOOKUP in a 1-to-many scenario by concatenating all values in matching rows
'  instead of just returning the first match
' Utilizes a dictionary to speedup multiple matches (great for array formulas)
Public Function VLOOKUP_MANY_ARRAY(lookup_values As Range, lookup_range As Range, column_number As Integer, Optional delimiter As Variant) As Variant
    Dim vHaystack As Variant, vNeedles As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim found As Boolean: found = False
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Set default delimiter
    If IsMissing(delimiter) Then delimiter = ", "

    ' Get values
    vHaystack = lookup_range
    vNeedles = lookup_values

    ' If column_number is outside of the specified range, return #REF
    If column_number < LBound(vHaystack, 2) Or column_number > UBound(vHaystack, 2) Then
        VLOOKUP_MANY_ARRAY = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Add values to a lookup dictionary
    For i = 1 To UBound(vHaystack, 1)
        If dict.Exists(UCase(vHaystack(i, 1))) Then
            dict.Item(UCase(vHaystack(i, 1))) = dict.Item(UCase(vHaystack(i, 1))) & delimiter & vHaystack(i, column_number)
        Else
            dict.Add UCase(vHaystack(i, 1)), vHaystack(i, column_number)
        End If
    Next

    Dim outArr As Variant
    If IsArray(vNeedles) Then ' Check number of lookup cells
        ' Build output array
        ReDim outArr(1 To UBound(vNeedles, 1), 1 To 1) As Variant

        For i = 1 To UBound(vNeedles, 1)
            If dict.Exists(UCase(vNeedles(i, 1))) Then
                outArr(i, 1) = dict.Item(UCase(vNeedles(i, 1)))
            Else
                outArr(i, 1) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
            End If
        Next
    Else
        ' Single output value
        If dict.Exists(UCase(vNeedles)) Then
            outArr = dict.Item(UCase(vNeedles))
        Else
            outArr = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        End If
    End If

    VLOOKUP_MANY_ARRAY = outArr
End Function
```

This creates a `Dictionary`, which is a special structure that's really good for looking up values. There's a little extra overhead involved in building it, but once you have the structure, you can do lookups into it very quickly. This is especially nice with array formulas, which is basically when the *exact* same formula gets put into a whole collection of cells, then the function executes once and returns values for every cell (instead of just executing once, separately, for a bunch of cells). Enter it like an array formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, and make the first argument refer to *all* your lookup values instead of just one.

It will work without being used as an array formula, but it will be somewhat slower than the first function in that situation. However, if you use it in an array formula, you'll see *huge* speedups.

Comment: Thank you - this is perfect

Comment: I'm having an issue when trying to use the array formula, The error is Argument not optional on the VLOOKUP_MANY = CVErr(xlErrRef) line of code. Any ideas what could be causing this I'm pretty sure I'm entering all variables required.

Comment: @Quinn Yeah, that line is wrong. I forgot to change the variable name while refactoring the code for use in an array formula. It should read `VLOOKUP_MANY_ARRAY = CVErr(xlErrRef)`. I'm not sure if this is exactly the issue you were having (that's not the error code I'd expect), but it's definitely an issue that's now been fixed.

Comment: One Last question I'm applying this UDF to different columns e,g Once for Risks and Once for Mitigation. Is there a way I can add an identifier at the start of each entry in the cell so I can match up across cells? e.g "1.Risk details.......2.Risk details etc."

Comment: @Quinn Not positive what you're saying. Kind of sounds like you'd like to go from applying two array formulas to two columns into using one array formula across both columns. Is is possible? Yes. But not trivially - it would be a pretty major edit. And it probably won't save you terribly much time either.

Comment: Apologies to be clear I was asking if it's possible to enter an incrementing identifier for each entry into a particular cell. So if cell x had three risks entered into it they would be identified by both the delimiter specified and a numerical value say 1.Risk 1- 2.Risk 2 3.Risk 3

Comment: @Quinn Doable, but not easily in this function. The current data structure has no extra space to easily store a "count" variable, so it would have to be refactored or we would need to add another structure alongside. More and more overhead... What I suggest instead is writing a UDF that takes the list this one outputs, and reformats it into a numbered list. It'll be less work this way. If you need help doing that, post up a new question, because we're veering out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 0):

RE-EDIT:

You might need to write a [user defined function](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/12/20/excel-udf-lookup-and-return-multiple-values-concatenated-into-one-cell/#concatenate) or write a macro (code on same link)

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer in the Risk log risks are recorded on separate lines, so one project may have 5+ risks on different lines. I don't think combining Vlookups can work with the way my data is currently. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Quinn You specified a 1:m relationship, so I think that was already pretty clear.

Comment: Will this bring back all results from the raw data, or just the first it finds? MATCH returns the first result it finds, and not all results it finds? Doesn't the OP need all results from the Raw Data in one field?

Comment: apparently I'm in Friday afternoon mode, sorry, it seems like you might want to use a user defined function