# Excel - Add sequential numbers to cell text based on line breaks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that contains information on projects. The worksheet contains a column which contains risks for each project. There is a one-to-many relationship between a project and its risks.

Currently the risks for a projects are added to single cell and separated by a line break. I need to add sequential identifiers at the start of each risk. So for example inside a particular cell it should look like this. The sequential number should be bold if at all possible.

1).**Risk 1

2).**Risk 2

3).**Risk 3

etc.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a formatting issue you can either sort it out manually or you want write a vba to add numbers after each line break (vbCrlf) character in the cell string. Split it using the line break as delimiter loop over each element of the array and concatenate sequence number to each string then put it all in the cell.

Comment: Not the clearest problem statement. You should probably link back to your previous post, maybe provide the current function you're using to create this output, at least specify that you want to use a UDF compatible with an array formula. Here's the original question for anyone interested in giving this a shot (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38920761/3397613) - see the comments for more info too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach it via UDF:

```
' Reformats a list from a simple delimitation to a numbered list
' Accepts arrays of strings for inList (allowing array formulas)
'  numFormat is a standard Excel-style format string (default "0. ")
'  inDelimiter is the delimiter in the input list
'  outDelimiter is the delimiter for the output list
Public Function TO_NUMBERED_LIST(inList As Variant, Optional numFormat As Variant, _
 Optional inDelimiter As Variant, Optional outDelimiter As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    ' Set default parameters
    If IsMissing(numFormat) Then numFormat = "0). "
    If IsMissing(inDelimiter) Then inDelimiter = vbNewLine
    If IsMissing(outDelimiter) Then outDelimiter = inDelimiter

    If IsArray(inList) Then ' Must loop through each entry if using as an array formula
        Dim outList() As Variant
        ReDim outList(0 To (UBound(inList) - LBound(inList)), 1 To 1)

        j = 0
        For i = LBound(inList) To UBound(inList)
            If IsError(inList(i, 1)) Then
                outList(j, 1) = inList(i, 1)
            Else
                outList(j, 1) = MakeNumbered(CStr(inList(i, 1)), CStr(numFormat), CStr(inDelimiter), CStr(outDelimiter))
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Next

        TO_NUMBERED_LIST = outList
    Else
        TO_NUMBERED_LIST = MakeNumbered(CStr(inList), CStr(numFormat), CStr(inDelimiter), CStr(outDelimiter))
    End If
End Function

' Helper function to do the actual work of splitting lists, numbering them, and recombining them
Private Function MakeNumbered(inList As String, Optional numFormat As String, _
 Optional inDelimiter As String, Optional outDelimiter As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tokenArr() As String
    tokenArr = Split(inList, inDelimiter)

    For i = 0 To UBound(tokenArr)
        tokenArr(i) = Format(i + 1, numFormat) & tokenArr(i)
    Next

    MakeNumbered = Join(tokenArr, outDelimiter)
End Function
```

I leverage some knowledge from your previous thread, like the fact that the input might be an array (and the whole function might be used in an array formula) but will only ever be 1-dimensional.

I've made this pretty general for reformatting. It can take in lists with any input delimiter (in your case, a newline) and output using any desired delimiter (in your case, still a newline). The `numFormat` parameter acts using the Format function and supports formats like you would commonly see in Excel. Check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) if you need help there.

Default parameters have already been tweaked for your example - newline as delimiter(s) and "0). " as numbering format.

Comment: Thank you for all your help

Comment: @Quinn Glad it worked for you. These sorts of reusable UDFs are easily the most fun things I write here on SO, because they could be reasonably useful and flexible in a general day-to-day workflow instead of being just one-off automation tasks.

Comment: I'm experiencing an "Automation Error" when I load the file this UDF is enabled on. The debugger is pointing too the function declaration at the start of the UDF as the problem. The UDFs data is being refreshed automatically from SharePoint when the file opens could this be causing a problem?

Comment: @Quinn "Automation Error" is about as broad as an error gets. Did it give you any other details (type/number of error)? This sort of error usually occurs when you expect a resource to exist and try to use it, but it can't be found/reached. Any chance the code is running with references to data not-yet-loaded-in, or that the worksheets using the UDF don't have access to the module where the function is defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Split` function on each cell value to create an array of risks and then prefix each risk with the sequence id. Then you can use the `Join` function to put the array back into a single value to update the cell with.

Depending on how the newlines got into the cell you might need to use `vbCrLf`, or `vbNewLine` instead of `vbLf` in the following example code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddRiskSequence()

    Dim rngRisks As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim varRisks As Variant
    Dim lngIndex As Long

    'set range with risk values
    Set rngRisks = Sheet2.Range("B2:B4")

    'iterate cells in risk column
    For Each rngCell In rngRisks
        'split cell contents by line feed into array
        varRisks = VBA.Split(rngCell.Value, vbLf)
        'iterate array and add sequence ids
        For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(varRisks)
            varRisks(lngIndex) = VBA.CStr(lngIndex + 1) & ") " & varRisks(lngIndex)
        Next lngIndex
        'rejoin array and update cell value
        rngCell.Value = VBA.Join(varRisks, vbLf)
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]